What is the response to muslims saying Vedas say Na Tasya Pratima Asti
Many use the Yajurvaid 32.3 to say murtipuja of the dwait followers and sampradiyas is not only against their religions but against ours too. what to say to this? I know for a fact that most Hindus I know don't believe what you see online about how we don't believe the idol is looking at Bhagwan, we do think it is looking at him not some lame way to just look at it and guess it is Bhagwan.

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/i-want-to-know-the-actual-meaning-of-na-tasya-pratima-asti-yajurveda-32-3

Entire Shloka is:
न तस्य प्रतिमा अस्ति यस्य नाम महाद्यशः |
हिरण्यगर्भऽ इत्येष मा मा हिंन्सिदितेषा यस्मान्न जातऽ इत्येषः ||

Entire meaning cannot be understood without context which says, He has no equivalence, (because) he is verily vast or his glory is verily great.

add some sources to your answer. Guideline is here.

The verse 'Na Tasya Pratima Asti' applies to Brahman. This is because the true nature of Brahman is not known.
No one Knows the true nature of Brahman

Príthiví (Earth).--Hail to thee, who art all creatures; to thee, the
holder of the mace and shell: elevate me now from this place, as thou
hast upraised me in days of old. From thee have I proceeded; of thee
do I consist; as do the skies, and all other existing things. Hail to
thee, spirit of the supreme spirit; to thee, soul of soul; to thee,
who art discrete and indiscrete matter; who art one with the elements
and with time. Thou art the creator of all things, their preserver,
and their destroyer, in the forms, oh lord, of Brahmá, Vishńu, and
Rudra, at the seasons of creation, duration, and dissolution. When
thou hast devoured all things, thou reposest on the ocean that sweeps
over the world, meditated upon, oh Govinda, by the wise. No one
knoweth thy true nature, and the gods adore thee only in the forms it
hath pleased thee to assume. They who are desirous of final
liberation, worship thee as the supreme Brahmá; and who that adores
not Vásudeva, shall obtain emancipation? Whatever may be apprehended
by the mind, whatever may be perceived by the senses, whatever may he
discerned by the intellect, all is but a form of thee. I am of thee,
upheld by thee; thou art my creator, and to thee I fly for refuge:
hence, in this universe, Mádhaví (the bride of Mádhava or Vishńu) is
my designation. Triumph to the essence of all wisdom, to the
unchangeable, the imperishable: triumph to the eternal; to the
indiscrete, to the essence of discrete things: to him who is both
cause and effect; who is the universe; the sinless lord of sacrifice
4; triumph. Thou art sacrifice; thou art the oblation; thou art the
mystic Omkára; thou art the sacrificial fires; thou art the Vedas, and
their dependent sciences; thou art, Hari, the object of all worship 5.
The sun, the stars, the planets, the whole world; all that is
formless, or that has form; all that is visible, or invisible; all,
Purushottama, that I have said, or left unsaid; all this, Supreme,
thou art. Hail to thee, again and again! hail! all hail!

Vishnu Purana I.4
Since the true nature is not known, i.e., human intellect can't grasp the idea of Brahman, no image can be made of Brahman, and only the forms manifested by Brahman can be worshipped. One can't conclude that murthi puja is forbidden. That would be too crude a conclusion.
In the language of philosophy Brahman is so transcendent that It is beyond the capacity of a human being to understand It. So where is the scope to create an Image of It?
Here are 2 additional verses that say that no one knows the true nature of Brahman.

Manu said, ‘Brahman is not an object of touch, or of hearing, or of
taste, or of sight, or of smell, or of any deductive inference from
the Known. Only the Understanding (when withdrawn from everything
else) can attain to it. All objects that the mind apprehends through
the senses are capable of being withdrawn into the mind; the mind can
be withdrawn into the understanding; the Understanding can be
withdrawn into the soul, and the Soul into the Supreme.’

Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCIV

Yajnavalkya said: O Gargi, it is the supreme being that the non-yogins
call gross but, in fact, that is eternal and wonderful lord; one that
is not long, not red, that has no head, that has no setting, hence
that has a lasting taste, that has no contact, no smell, no juice, no
eyes, no ears, neither speech nor mind, no brilliance, no proof [or
magnitude], no (worldly) happiness, no name, no race, no death, no
age, no ailment; that is nectarine, that is expressed by the word Om,
that is immortal, that has neither a predecessor nor a successor, that
is endless and non-external. It eats something. It does not eat
anything. ..

Linga Purana II.9.53–54
Universe and gods and goddesses are manifestations of Brahman

There are two states of this Brahman; one with, and one without shape;
one perishable, and one imperishable; which are inherent in all
beings. The imperishable is the supreme being; the perishable is all
the world. The blaze of fire burning on one spot diffuses light and
heat around; so the world is nothing more than the manifested energy
of the supreme Brahman: and inasmuch, Maitreya, as the light and heat
are stronger or feebler as we are near to the fire, or far off from
it, so the energy of the supreme is more or less intense in the beings
that are less or more remote from him. Brahma, Vishńu, and Śiva are
the most powerful energies of god; next to them are the inferior
deities, then the attendant spirits, then men, then animals, birds,
insects, vegetables; each becoming more and more feeble as they are
farther from their primitive source. In this way, illustrious Brahman,
this whole world, although in essence imperishable and eternal,
appears and disappears, as if it was subject to birth and death.
The supreme condition of Brahman, which is meditated by the Yogis in
the commencement of their abstraction, as invested with form, is
Vishńu, composed of all the divine energies, and the essence of
Brahman, with whom the mystic union that is sought, and which is
accompanied by suitable elements, is effected by the devotee whose
whole mind is addressed to that object. This Hari, who is the most
immediate of all the energies of Brahma, is his embodied shape,
composed entirely of his essence; and in him therefore is the whole
world interwoven; and from him, and in him, is the universe; and he,
the supreme lord of all, comprising all that is perishable and
imperishable, bears upon him all material and spiritual existence,
identified in nature with his ornaments and weapons.

Vishnu Purana I.22.55-65
There are numerous scriptural verses that support murthi worship of the deities manifested by Brahman.
The vigraha or Image should be thought of as a hotel where a special presence of God resides when pranapratistha is successfully carried out. The reverse can also be done. God can be requested to vacate the Image and then the Image is discarded.
Avahana and Visarjana

Either partially or wholly he should recite the mantras for adoring
limbs and adore them, circumambulate them and then offer offerings. He
should meditate in his mind, “I am Brahma, Hari” and should utter the
word “come” in the ceremony of avahana [1] (invocation) and the words
“forgive me” in the rite of Visarjana.[2]

Agni Purana 23.18–19
[1] It is a religious rite of the Hindus by which they install life in the murti made for worship.
[2] A rite in which the life given is sent away and the murti is thrown away.

In every figure he hath been the mode; this is his only form for us to
look on. Indra moves multiform by his illusions; for his Bay Steeds
are yoked, ten times a hundred.

Rig Veda VI.47.18
Basic elements of Murti or Pratima Puja are there in the Rig Veda itself. The idea that a Devata can enter every figure and has many forms allows one to do Murti puja.

A man should, however, worship Me in images, side by side with
discharging his duties, which include the love of all beings, until he
actually realises My presence in in himself and in all beings. As long
as man is self-centered and makes an absolute distinction between
himself and others (without recognizing the unity of all in Me, the
Inner Pervader), he will be subject to the great fear of Death
(including every form of deprivation of self-interest). So, overcoming
the separateness of a self-centered life, one should serve all beings
with gifts, honor and love, recognizing that such service is really
being rendered to Me who reside in all beings as their innermost soul.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27

Whoever makes an offering to Me with devotion, be it of leaf, flower,
fruit or water - that devout offering made by a pure-hearted man, I
accept with joy.

Gita 9.26
Where would you put these offerings if there is no murthi or image?
Idol worship is beneficial

Henceforth, I shall mention the benefit accruing from the installation
of the idol entirely, for the welfare of the world. The idol may be in
accordance with one’s own wish.

Linga Purana I.76.1
Image worship is based on the principle of love.

Master (to the teacher): “What is wrong with image worship? The
Vedanta says that Brahman manifests Itself where there is ‘Existence,
Light, and Love’. Therefore nothing exists but Brahman.”

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, With the Devotees at Dakshineswar (II)
Instruction for Images by Sri Krishna

My images for worship are of eight kinds- those made of stone, wood,
metals, sand, or precious stones, those drawn on the floor, those in
the shape of a picture, and those mentally conceived. Images, which
are the veritable tabernacles of the Lord, are of two kinds, the fixed
and the movable. There is no need, O Uddhava, for Avahana (invoking
divine presence) and Udvasa (vacating the presence) in the case of
fixed images. In them the presence is permanent.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.27.12–13
